# Different shipping method: Ubercart

Tags: php, drupal-6, ubercart

I am facing some serious problem in ubercart. I have 2 term in taxonomy, Door handles and Entrance doors. When I upload a product from adding content type product, i am choosing the parent item(eg. Door handles or Entrance doors).
But problem is that, i need different shipping method for each category. That means shipping price of handles and entrance door are different.
I have create two faltrate and putting condition on it by choosing catalog terms from here: admin > store > settings > quotes > methods > flatrate

But when I carting two or more different category of product then Ubercart gives two option to choose the flat rate.

I think this is not the right proceduce, can anbody help me out? I am using drupal 6.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this module myself but [UC Catalog Conditional Actions](http://drupal.org/project/ca_catalog_terms) apparently allows you to set up shipping quote conditions based on taxonomy.